# How to plot data composed of two parts in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I added two treatments to my experiment object. Before treatment, at each time point, it had 4 replicates, since it was treated with two conditions, under each condition, it had 2 replicates. I want to plot data like shown in the picture below. But I don't know how to connect the time point between 0h and 1h.

I want the plot to be: 
[image]

But my current plots are like this:
[image]

Some data to help illustrate my question:

```
| Treatment     | Time      | Replicate | Read      |
|------------   |-------    |-------    |-------    |
| Untreated     | -3        | 1         | 26        |
| Untreated     | -3        | 2         | 25        |
| Untreated     | -3        | 3         | 25        |
| Untreated     | -3        | 4         | 26        |
| Untreated     | -2        | 1         | 20        |
| Untreated     | -2        | 2         | 19        |
| Untreated     | -2        | 3         | 19        |
| Untreated     | -2        | 4         | 20        |
| Untreated     | -1        | 1         | 14        |
| Untreated     | -1        | 2         | 13        |
| Untreated     | -1        | 3         | 13        |
| Untreated     | -1        | 4         | 14        |
| Untreated     | 0         | 1         | 8         |
| Untreated     | 0         | 2         | 7         |
| Untreated     | 0         | 3         | 7         |
| Untreated     | 0         | 4         | 8         |
| Treatment1    | 1         | 1         | 14        |
| Treatment1    | 1         | 2         | 13        |
| Treatment2    | 1         | 1         | 11        |
| Treatment2    | 1         | 2         | 10        |
| Treatment1    | 2         | 1         | 20        |
| Treatment1    | 2         | 2         | 19        |
| Treatment2    | 2         | 1         | 14        |
| Treatment2    | 2         | 2         | 13        |
| Treatment1    | 3         | 1         | 26        |
| Treatment1    | 3         | 2         | 25        |
| Treatment2    | 3         | 1         | 17        |
| Treatment2    | 3         | 2         | 16        |
```

My current code is following:

```
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Function to calculate the mean and the standard deviation for each group
# data : a data frame
# varname : the name of a column containing the variable to be summariezed
# groupnames : vector of column names to be used as grouping variables
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++
data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames) {
    summary_func <- function(x, col) {
        c(
            mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm = TRUE),
            sem = sd(x[[col]], na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(length(x[[col]]))
        )
    }
    require(plyr)
    data_sum <- ddply(data, groupnames,
        .fun = summary_func,
        varname
    )
    data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
    return(data_sum)
}


ggplot(
    data_summary(my_data,
        varname = "Read",
        groupnames = c("Time", "Treatment")
    ),
    aes(
        x = Time,
        y = Read,
        color = Treatment
    )
) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Read - sem, ymax = Read + sem),
    width = .1,
    position = position_dodge(0.05) # Use this to move overlapped errorbars horizontally
) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(size = 2.5) +
    labs(x = "Time since treatment (h)", y = "Read") +
    theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add two rows after you summarize the data to connect the dots. For those two rows, you will need to provide the mean. The se, upper, bound and lower bound would all be NA.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Treatment, Time) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(Read), Se = sd(Read)/sqrt(n())) %>%
  mutate(Upper = Mean + Se, Lower = Mean - Se)

dat3 <- dat2 %>% split(f = .$Treatment)

dat4 <- map_dfr(dat3, function(x){
  temp <- tibble(Treatment = unique(x$Treatment),
                 Time = 0, 
                 Mean = min(dat2$Mean), 
                 Se = NA,
                 Upper = NA,
                 Lower = NA)
  y <- bind_rows(temp, x)
  return(y)
})

ggplot(dat4, aes(x = Time, y = Mean, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper),
                width = .1,
                position = position_dodge(0.05)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  labs(x = "Time since treatment (h)", y = "Read") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Treatment         Time        Replicate   Read      
 Untreated      -3  1   26
 Untreated      -3  2   25
 Untreated      -3  3   25
 Untreated      -3  4   26
 Untreated      -2  1   20
 Untreated      -2  2   19
 Untreated      -2  3   19
 Untreated      -2  4   20
 Untreated      -1  1   14
 Untreated      -1  2   13
 Untreated      -1  3   13
 Untreated      -1  4   14
 Untreated      0   1   8
 Untreated      0   2   7
 Untreated      0   3   7
 Untreated      0   4   8
 Treatment1     1   1   14
 Treatment1     1   2   13
 Treatment2     1   1   11
 Treatment2     1   2   10
 Treatment1     2   1   20
 Treatment1     2   2   19
 Treatment2     2   1   14
 Treatment2     2   2   13
 Treatment1     3   1   26
 Treatment1     3   2   25
 Treatment2     3   1   17
 Treatment2     3   2   16",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Actually those vertical lines on my plot are error bars representing SEM, I think adding two rows will affect the calculation of the SEM. I just attached the code I'm using for reference.

Comment: @firefox Please see my update. This is the same idea. You just need to add two more rows after you summarized the data.